# accessing xml node value

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have xml file like

```
<House>
   <Name>some name</Name>
   <Price>22223</Price>
</House>
```

I'm loading file using XElement and I'm selecting it's elements

```
XElement elem = XElement.Load(fileName);
var houseElements = from h in elem.Elements() select h;
```

question is: how to access values inside each element inside this file
I tried with

```
model.Name = houseElements.Where(x => x.Name == "Name").Select(x => x.Value).ToString();
model.Price= Convert.ToInt16(houseElements.Where(x => x.Name == "Price").Select(x => x.Value));
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: "*but this doesn't work*" is too broad. surely you know [ask]...

Comment: Hint: you shouldn't need `.Where()` for this. look at `.Element("tagName")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select`, `Where` and other LINQ methods return an [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) (like a collection), not a single item.

The reason for this is that there could be many items with the specified name.

But since you know for sure that there is a single item, you can to get the first item (via  [the `First()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx)) like this:

```
var Name =
    houseElements
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Name")
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .First();

var Price =
    Convert.ToInt16(
        houseElements
        .Where(x => x.Name == "Price")
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .First());
```

Here is a better version of the code:

```
var Name =
    houseElements
    .Elements("Name")
    .First()
    .Value;

var Price =
    Convert.ToInt16(
        houseElements
        .Elements("Price")
        .First()
        .Value);
```

Comment: If you know for sure there is a single item and multiple occurences is an error, you should use `Single` and not `First`